# Membership provider - 2 different databases

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I have been researching a way to use membership provider when 2 different databases are involved in MVC3.

Here is the problem.

When the user logs in, Database A is used to get the roles and permissions
After successful login the data is handled from Database B. I have a custom provider.

When looking one of the solutions was to change the connection string during run time in the custom provider. But I am not sure when and where to do it.

If there are any other elegant way of handling roles and permission please point to me in that direction.

Thank you

Comment: Can someone please help me, with guidance, how I can achieve calls to different databases using Membership provider.

If that's not possible how can I achieve the desired result.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342158/using-multiple-membership-providers-within-asp-net-mvc-3-application